# Qtip only works for <a href> tags, nothing else, despite clean, responsive dbug tool consoles

Tags: jquery, html, qtip

I loaded up Qtip into a very simple test html page just to see if I could make it work.  It works as intended for < a > tags, but I can't get it to work with any other element.  I have played around with the JQuery version and a variety of selectors and content types.
Any ideas of what I did wrong here?
It's really throwing me for a loop that it will work with SOME elements and not others.

In addition, the h1 /h2 tags will generate normal tooltips, so seemingly the titles are correctly formatted, they just fail to pull in qtip.

Here's my code, within the body:

```
<h1 title='this is the h1 title'>I can haz a tooltip?</h1>
<h2 title='this is the h2 title'>this is an h2</h2>
<h2 title='this is the h2 title'>this is an h2</h2>
<h2 title='this is the h2 title'>this is an h2</h2>

<a href="" data-content='will this title change at all?'>here is a test link</a>
<a href="" data-content='will this title change at all?'>here is a test link</a>
<a href="" data-content='will this title change at all?'>here is a test link</a>
<a href="" data-content='will this title change at all?'>here is a test link</a>
```

And then further down, at the end of the page here's my jquery logic:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a').qtip({   //DOES work correctly
            content: {
                text: function () {
                    return $(this).attr("data-content");
                } 
            }
        });

     $('h2').qtip({ // does NOT work
             content: {
                        text: 'does the h2 get a tooltip here yet'
                    }
        });

    $('h2').qtip(); //also tried this and does NOT work
    $('h1').qtip(); //also does not work


        console.log('I am ready now');
    });


 </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does work,

It's just that by default the `h1` and `h2` tags are 100% wide so you end up getting the qTip off the right-hand-side. Setting them to a fixed width works:

CSS:

```
h1, h2 {
    width:300px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/gr287/

Comment: holy cow, I can't believe it was that simple.  you're the best person ever, thanks